# Castle: delegate-based factory lifestyle?

Tags: castle-windsor

Whats the lifestyle of the implicit delegate-factory in the TypedFactoryFacility? Since the components created by the factory are released when the factory is released I am guessing that it registers as transient, but can anyone please confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are registered as transient.